# On the specifics of illegitimate children

Tags: vocabulary, slang, grammatical-gender, kinship-terms

Is there a feminine form of the word *bastard*? It seems like *bastard* is a word that’s applied to male children only.

Comment: The male tilt on bastard may be due to there being no male form of "bitch." At least, that's why I was using it.

Comment: @hrhen: Bitch is definitely equivalent in terms of profanity, at least in modern english. I'm specifically looking for something that has the older connotation, before it became a general pejorative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Talking about the archaic use of *bastard* to mean “illegitimate child”, it is not specifically masculine. One can talk about a “bastard daugther” just as much as one can talk of a “bastard son” or “bastard child”, as [Google ngram](//books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bastard%20child,bastard%20son,bastard%20daughter&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows. Well, not as much, because lineage or legitimacy is not nearly as important for daughters as it is for sons, but still, such usage is attested.

Comment: Also note that "bastardized" can be used to describe anything created illegitimately. Although in later times (Victorian era onward) the idea of a child being bastard (adj.) has carried increasing moral opprobrium, originally the stronger meaning of the term focused on rights to inherit property.

Comment: Probably why in literature it mainly applies to sons - it didn't matter if a daughter is legitimate or not

Answer (score 1):

The human rights organization [Bastard Nation](http://www.bastards.org/FAQ.html) suggests the term has always been gender neutral. Certainly a bastard child could be male or female.

Answer (score 0):

Typical with religious institutions, Latin terms were used in Parish birth records:

**[Nothus](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/nothus)** (gnothus) bastard, illegitimate

**Filia nothus** for female girl

**Filius nothus** for male child

Comment: Shouldn't it be **filia notha**? Or did they not know Latin in the parish churches?

Comment: @PeterShor  Latin words and abbreviations

Fil = Son or Daughter:  Filius = Son:  Filia = Daughter:
  Nothus = Illegitimate:  Uxor = Wife: Vid = Widow: http://www.kidwellyhistory.co.uk/Registers/Intro.htm

Comment: In [Latin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nothus), the adjectives get declined to match the gender of the noun: **nothus** for masculine, **notha** for feminine, **nothum** for neuter. So it should be **filia notha**, unless whoever is recording the birth records knows no Latin whatsoever.

Comment: I looked at several parish/genealogy/township records and they were consistent with this use -Consuetudo, jus et norma loquendi

Comment: *nothus*, *notus* or *gnotus* literally means *known* and should decline in agreement with its noun. In this context it should be for illegitimate children recognised by their fathers.  If unrecognised, *ignotus* would be the better Latin.